# Fullpage JavaScript and CSS 3 animation

Tags: javascript, css, fullpage.js

I am new to [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) and [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery).

I would like to ask one question about `fullpage.js`. I am making a slider with a caption. My slider image is on right side and caption on the left side. I want to add an `animate.css` animation on the caption. I want two types of animations, one is wayin and the other wayout on the caption. I read some documentation of *fullpage.js* and tried with a callback function. However, it did not work for me.

I meant when the user clicks on, let's say, the second slide caption it will come from the bottom along with a slide I want to add the animate.css effect `fadeInUP` on the caption. When the user clicks the third slide, the second slide caption go up with a `fadeOutUp` effect and a new slide came in with `fadeInUp` effect on caption. I hope it makes sense.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionSelector:'.section',
    css3:true,
    navigationPosition: 'left',
    navigation: false,
    slidesNavigation: false,
    controlArrows: false,
    anchors: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14'],
    menu: '#myMenu'
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: apercuregular,Helvetica,Arial;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-size: 18px;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h6 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-family: inherit;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

a,
a:link,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

.wrap {
  /* height: calc(100% - 60px);
  border:1px solid black;
  margin-left:30px;
  margin-right:30px;
  margin-top:30px;
  margin-bottom:30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*padding: 10px;*/
  /*z-index: 100;*/
}

.wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 90px;
  left: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.container-fluid {
  /*height: 100%;*/
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  /*background: gray;*/
}

.mycaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 25%;
}

.overflow {
  z-index: 100;
}

.logo {
  height: 45px;
  width: 160px;
  /*margin-top: 0px;*/
  margin-left: 7px;
}

.navbar-custom {
  background: none;
  background-image: none;
  background-repeat: none;
  height: 70px;
}

.caret {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background-image: url(../img/sprite.png);
  background-position: -17px -117px;
  border-top:none;
}

.navbar {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
  color: #555;
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #000;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  color: #000;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.nav .open>a, .nav .open>a:focus, .nav .open>a:hover {
  background-color: none;
  border-color: #337ab7;
}

/* side navigtion style and animation  */
#myMenu {
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:0;
}

#myMenu li {
  list-style: none;
}

.fp-controlArrow {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
  top: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: none;
  margin-top: -38px;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

a.close span{
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  right: 40px;
  background-image: url(../img/sprite.png);
  background-position: -14px 0;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
}

a.close span:hover{
  transform:rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
}

.mycaption a span.forwardarrow {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  bottom: -25px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 14px;
  background-image: url(../img/sprite.png);
  background-position: 0px -90px;
}

span#mainexit:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

span#mainexit {
  position: absolute;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  top: 50px;
  right: 35px;
  background: url('../img/sprite.png');
  background-position: -14px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 13;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
}


.mainavigationmenu li {
  padding: 5px;
}

a span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

mark {
  background-color: transparent;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  color: #071689;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}

a span.visual ,
a span.merchandising,
a span.in,
a span.work,
a span.event,
a span.fitouts,
a span.joi,
a span.ery,
a span.metal,
a span.fabrication,
a span.instore,
a span.branding,
a span.office,
a span.fitouts,
a span.wood,
a span.works,
a span.branding,
a span.giveaways,
a span.digital,
a span.printing {
  display: inline-block;
  width:0;
  opacity: 0;

  /*-webkit-transition: all 0.4s linear; /* Safari */
  /*transition: all  0.4s linear;*/
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55); /* Safari */
  transition: all  0.6s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

a:hover span.visual,
a:hover span.merchandising {
  opacity: 1;
  width:40px;
  /*vertical-align: bottom;*/
  font-weight: normal;
}

a:hover span.in,
a:hover span.work {
  opacity: 1;
  width:62px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

a:hover span.event,
a:hover span.fitouts {
  opacity: 1;
  width:40px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

a:hover span.joi,
a:hover span.ery {
  opacity: 1;
  width:15px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

a:hover span.metal,
a:hover span.fabrication {
  opacity: 1;
  width:35px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

a:hover span.instore,
a:hover span.branding {
  opacity: 1;
  width:55px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

a:hover span.office,
a:hover span.fitouts {
  opacity: 1;
  width:40px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

a:hover span.wood,
a:hover span.works {
  opacity: 1;
  width:35px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

a:hover span.branding,
a:hover span.giveaways {
  opacity: 1;
  width:70px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

a:hover span.digital,
a:hover span.printing {
  opacity: 1;
  width:45px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.7.7/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.7.7/jquery.fullPage.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom">
        <div class="container-fluid overflow">
          <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
              <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="alphbetic">
            </a>
          </div>
          <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;menu</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#">WHERE CREATIVITY TAKES SHAPE</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- End col-lg-12 DIV -->
  </div>
  <!-- End row DIV -->
  <div class="wrap">
    <!-- <div id="fullpage"> -->
    <div id="fullpage" class="container-fluid">
      <div id="section0" class="section row active">
        <div class="slide">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="mycaption">
              <a class="fp-controlArrow fp-next" href="#">
                <h1>Visual<br>Merchandising</h1>
                <p>Cras justo odio</p>
                <span class="forwardarrow"></span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Ends .col-lg-6 DIV -->
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/1160/1392/food" alt="alphabetic">
          </div>
          <!-- Ends .col-lg-6 DIV -->
        </div>
        <!-- Ends slide DIV -->

        <div class="slide">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <p>Text Detail</p>
              </div>
              <!-- Ends col-lg-6 DIV -->
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/1160/1392/food" alt="alphabetic">
              </div>
              <!-- Ends col-lg-6 DIV -->

              <!-- <a class="close fp-controlArrow fp-next" href="#"></a><span></span> -->

              <a href="#"><span id="mainexit" class="myexit fp-controlArrow fp-next"></span></a>
            </div>
            <!-- Ends Row DIV -->
          </div>
          <!-- Ends container-fluid DIV -->
        </div>
        <!-- Ends Slide -->
      </div>
      <!-- Ends Row DIV -->
      <div id="section1" class="section row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="mycaption">
            <a href="vm.html">
              <h1>Interior<br>Works</h1>
              <p>Cras justo odio</p>
              <span class="forwardarrow"></span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Ends .col-lg-6 DIV -->
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/1160/1392/city" alt="alphabetic">
        </div>
        <!-- Ends .col-lg-6 DIV -->

        <!-- Ends Section.vertical-scrolling -->
      </div>
      <!-- Ends Row DIV -->

      <div id="section2" class="section row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="mycaption">
            <a href="vm.html">
              <h1>Event<br>FitOuts</h1>
              <p>Cras justo odio</p>
              <span class="forwardarrow"></span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Ends .col-lg-6 DIV -->
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/1160/1392/sports" alt="alphabetic">
        </div>
        <!-- Ends .col-lg-6 DIV -->

        <!-- Ends Section.vertical-scrolling -->
      </div>
      <!-- Ends Row DIV -->

      <div id="section3" class="section row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="mycaption">
            <a href="vm.html">
              <h1>Joi<br>Nery</h1>
              <p>Cras justo odio</p>
              <span class="forwardarrow"></span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Ends .col-lg-6 DIV -->
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/1160/1392/transport" alt="alphabetic">
        </div>
        <!-- Ends .col-lg-6 DIV -->
      </div>
      <!-- Ends Row DIV -->
    </div>
    <!-- Ends container-fluid -->
  </div>
  <!-- Ends Fullpage DIV -->
  <ul id="myMenu">
    <li data-menuanchor="1" class="active">
      <a href="#1"><strong><mark>V</mark><span class="visual">isual&nbsp;</span><mark>M</mark><span class="merchandising">erchandising</span></strong>
      </a><br>
    </li>
    <li data-menuanchor="2"><a href="#2"><strong><mark>I</mark><span class="in">nterior&nbsp;</span><mark>W</mark><span class="work">orks</span></strong></a>
    </li>
    <li data-menuanchor="3"><a href="#3"><strong><mark>E</mark><span class="event">vent&nbsp;</span><mark>F</mark><span class="fitouts">itouts</span></strong></a>
    </li>
    <li data-menuanchor="4"><a href="#4"><strong><mark>J</mark><span class="joi">oi&nbsp;</span><mark>N</mark><span class="ery">ery</span></strong></a>
    </li>
    <li data-menuanchor="5"><a href="#5"><strong><mark>M</mark><span class="metal">etal&nbsp;</span><mark>F</mark><span class="fabrication">abrication</span>
      </strong></a>
    </li>
    <li data-menuanchor="6"><a href="#6"><strong><mark>I</mark><span class="instore">nstore&nbsp;</span><mark>B</mark><span class="branding">randing</span>
      </strong></a>
    </li>
    <li data-menuanchor="7"><a href="#7"><strong><mark>O</mark><span class="office">ffice&nbsp;</span><mark>F</mark><span class="fitouts">itouts</span>
      </strong></a>
    </li>
    <li data-menuanchor="8"><a href="#8"><strong><mark>W</mark><span class="wood">ood&nbsp;</span><mark>W</mark><span class="works">orks</span></strong></a>
    </li>
    <li data-menuanchor="9"><a href="#9"><strong><mark>B</mark><span class="branding">randing&nbsp;</span><mark>G</mark><span class="giveaways">iveaways</span>
      </strong></a>
    </li>
    <li data-menuanchor="10"><a href="#10"><strong><mark>D</mark><span class="digital">igital&nbsp;</span><mark>P</mark><span class="printing">rinting</span>
      </strong></a>
    </li>
    <li data-menuanchor="11"><a href="#11"><span class="square"></span></a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="12"><a href="#12"><span class="diamond"></span></a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="13"><a href="#13"><span class="plus">+</span></a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="14"><a href="#14"><span class="mapmkaer"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- Ends Wrap DIV -->
```

Here is a [**jsfiddle example**](https://jsfiddle.net/sd16syz9/9/).

Note: Please expand the window to see the effect.

Comment: Thanks Mi-Creativity for editing. Do you have any solution ?

Comment: You welcome, and nope I'm sorry I don't use such libraries I'd rather write my own code,  but you can when a specific slide is sliding *into* or *out from* the view and add the corresponding fading class

Comment: When you say `caption` do you mean the part who marked in [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PPH8c.jpg) image?

Comment: Yes. Do you have any solution Mosh Feu